# Sorting 2 php arrays based on its contents

Tags: php, arrays

So basically I have two arrays:

```
Array1
(
    [0] => BitTorrent
    [1] => Microsoft Remote Desktop
    [2] => RDC-lielais
    [3] => SSHasus
)
```

AND

```
Array
(
    [0] => BitTorrent protocol=tcp portrange=6881-6889
    [1] => Microsoft Remote Desktop protocol=tcp portrange=3389-3389
    [2] => Microsoft Remote Desktop protocol=udp portrange=3389-3389
    [3] => RDC-lielais protocol=tcp baseport=3389 portrange=3391-3391
    [4] => RDC-lielais protocol=udp baseport=3389 portrange=3391-3391
    [5] => SSHasus protocol=tcp portrange=24680-24680
    [6] => BitTorrent host=192.168.1.104 log=disabled
    [7] => Microsoft Remote Desktop host=192.168.1.111 log=disabled
    [8] => RDC-lielais host=192.168.1.104 log=disabled
    [9] => SSHasus host=192.168.1.102 log=disabled
)
```

And what a want achieve something like this. The idea is for each service to get info about it from another array. Tried all kind of looping through, but nothing works for me.

```
 Array
    (
            [0] => BitTorrent
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => BitTorrent protocol=tcp portrange=6881-6889
                    [1] => BitTorrent host=192.168.1.104 log=disabled
                )
            [2] => Microsoft Remote Desktop
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Microsoft Remote Desktop protocol=tcp portrange=3389-3389
                    [1] => Microsoft Remote Desktop protocol=udp portrange=3389-3389
                    [2] => Microsoft Remote Desktop host=192.168.1.111 log=disabled
                )
            [4] => RDC-lielais
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => RDC-lielais protocol=tcp baseport=3389 portrange=3391-3391
                    [1] => RDC-lielais protocol=udp baseport=3389 portrange=3391-3391
                    [2] => RDC-lielais host=192.168.1.104 log=disabled
                )
            [6] => SSHasus
            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SSHasus protocol=tcp portrange=24680-24680
                    [1] => SSHasus host=192.168.1.102 log=disabled
                )
    )
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the kinds of looping you tried?

Comment: why not use `RDC-lielais` and the others as your new array's keys? then you simply push/unshift the other array's strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was pretty simple, I just looped and checked whether each line of `$info` started with one of the app names:

```
<?php

$apps = array('BitTorrent', 'Microsoft Remote Desktop', 'RDC-lielais', 'SSHasus');
$info = array('BitTorrent protocol=tcp portrange=6881-6889',
'Microsoft Remote Desktop protocol=tcp portrange=3389-3389',
'Microsoft Remote Desktop protocol=udp portrange=3389-3389',
'RDC-lielais protocol=tcp baseport=3389 portrange=3391-3391',
'RDC-lielais protocol=udp baseport=3389 portrange=3391-3391',
'SSHasus protocol=tcp portrange=24680-24680',
'BitTorrent host=192.168.1.104 log=disabled',
'Microsoft Remote Desktop host=192.168.1.111 log=disabled',
'RDC-lielais host=192.168.1.104 log=disabled',
'SSHasus host=192.168.1.102 log=disabled');

$result = array();

foreach ($apps as $app) {

    $result[] = $app;
    $result[] = array();
    end($result);

    foreach ($info as $line) {

        if (strpos($line, $app) === 0) {

            $result[key($result)][] = $line;

        }

    }

}

var_dump($result);
```

This outputs the data in the format you requested in your question.

Comment: Thank you. That's worded fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through an array, and perform a [preg-grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to search your other array with a regular expression. For example; (I've made it a case-insensitive search by using the `i` flag)

```
<?php

$arrToSearch = array(
  "foo",
  "batman",
  "something"
);

$arrOther = array(
  "foo is the meaning of life, according to bar",
  "batman didn't like living in wayne manor",
  "batman praises the joker at night"
);

$arrFinalArray = array();
foreach($arrToSearch as $strToSearch) {
    $arrFinalArray[$strToSearch] = preg_grep("/". $strToSearch ."/i", $arrOther);
}


echo print_r($arrFinalArray, true);
```

https://eval.in/194770